# Localization of a ring isomorphism and algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, ring-homomorphism

> Let $\phi:R\rightarrow S$ be a homomorphism and $S$ an $R-$algebra. Moreover, let $T\subseteq R$ be a multiplicative group. Prove that $T^{-1}S$ is a $T^{-1}R$ algebra and that $T^{-1}S\simeq \phi(T)^{-1}S$.

I was able to prove the first part (straight from definition). The other part is where I'm having problems. I defined $\varphi:T^{-1}S\rightarrow \phi(T)^{-1}S$, $\varphi(\frac{s}{t})=\frac{s}{\phi(t)}$. This is obviously a surjective homomorphism but I wasn't able to prove that its $1-1$. I assumed $\frac{s}{\phi(t)}=\frac{s'}{\phi(t')}$, therefore there exists $\phi(m)$ s.t $\phi(m)(\phi(t')s-\phi(t)s')=0$ but wasn't able to take it from there.

Another approach I tried was showing that both $T^{-1}S$ and $\phi(T)^{-1}S$ are solutions to the universal property of the same localization problem, but that didn't work out either.

Any help would  be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What does $\frac{s}{t} = \frac{s'}{t'}$ mean? That there exists $m \in T$ such that $m \cdot (t' \cdot s - t \cdot s') = 0$. Here the $\cdot$ denotes the $R$-action on $S$. But by definition $r \cdot s = \phi(r)s$, so this equation is simply a restatement of $\phi(m)(\phi(t')s - \phi(t)s') = 0$.

Comment: Is this part of the definition of being a $R-$ algebra?

Comment: Well, you can define $R$-algebras a couple of ways, but for my money the best is simply a ring homomorphism $R \to S$ (say in the commutative case, for simplicity). In any case, the localization is a module-theoretic notion and only cares about the $R$-module structure on $S$. That $R$-module structure is given by $\phi$ using $r \cdot s := \phi(r)s$.